Review ESP32-based project with PMA8403 MT3608 TLC5947 and PCF8575
it's been a very long time I did not made an electronic project and... I've not selected the easiest to start back. I did some electronics during my engineer studies, but then I did not practice, been mostly an embedded SW Dev. So basically, noob here warning. :) If you were very kind enough to review the below project and also don't hesistate to explain things that I copied from designs seen on the web, advices, ...
The project has 24 leds, 24 hall sensors... yeah, december is coming (and winter too). Idea is an advent calendar, on the said day, the box blinks (to help the little one find the right one), there is a detection of the box being opened (magnets + hall sensors), and a tune/a story is played. If I have time, there will be a little sound & light show, opening a previous box will play the story again, opening a box too early will play a no-no message, ...
The thing is driven by an ESP32, probably using WiFi to download new stories/tunes and being controlled from the parents. The power is ensured by a typical phone power bank (10000mAh/5V/20W) directly to the ESP32 board. The ESP is 3V3 based, but most of the external modules seem work better under 5V (Arduino-like) and most of them have their own power regulator and inversion protection. I included a general switch through MOSFET so that the ESP32 can turn all modules off if needed.
The speaker driver is connected via I2S from the ESP. I too the resistor values from an available tutorial online, but I'll appreciate an explanation. I have no idea what they do. Not impedance adaption, it seem, divider bridge would be strange as the PAM accepts 5V and ESP delivers 3V3...
This tutorial also recommends a 1000uF 10V capacitor to reduce voltage drops in the circuit due to the speakers.
The LEDs are 12V, so I'm not sure I'll drive them that high, but they are not directly visible, each light a set of optic fibers (4-5), so I want to keep the option to raise the voltage to get more brightness. I use a 24 channels PWM module from Adafruit to drive them. There is a 3.3kOhm resistor to limit the current in the leds, but if I choose to go 12V, do I need to increase the resistor already on the module (there are holes to solder an extra resistor on the module). The module is driven using SPI, but the latch looks inverted, so I did not included a pull-up, the tutorials include no resistor, not even a pull-down. The module is able to work with a 3V3 SPI, I should not need to adjust the levels.
I had more troubles with the Hall sensors. It was hard to find a non-latched one, so I finally selected the A3144 and ordered 60pcs (I have two calendars to build) because time is ticking for part deliveries. In the end, the chose is not very good, because the magnets are present all the time unless the box is opened. So the sensor is almost always "on", and with my (surely inexact but hopefully not too far) computations, they drain each 0.56mA, so 13.2mA all the 24 of them. All the time. So I decided to using a polling mechanism instead of the interrupt capacity of the IO expander. That's why there is an extra MOSFET switch. The Hall sensors will be polled at 2 or 4Hz. Routine will be: Activate IO32, sleep a bit, send the module the configuration for all inputs, read back ports, switch IO32 off. The two modules are driven using I2C. I read that pull-up resistors are needed. There are pads at the back of the module (not shown in Fritzing), that can be soldered to select the I2C address (necessary as I need 2 modules per project).
Given the short timing and number of pieces (2), I don't think about ordering a PCB. But maybe you have arguments to say differently. I'm thinking about a perfboard for the two MOSFET switches and the ESP32 connections. And for the Hall sensors, I was planning to solder an SMD resistor between the two pins for each of them. But... maybe that's not a good idea?
Thanks for all inputs and feedback!
Edit:
I added a SPI SD Card Reader and I improved my skills with Fritzing, net labels and weird cable connection points!

(Breadboard is ugly with SD Card reader, so I did not included this mess. Tell me if you prefer this view, I'll post it.)
Old design and breadboard for ref:


